# How to work with jpegoptim multithread, and skip fails

Tags: segmentation-fault, find, sh, xargs, jpegoptim

I use this command:

```
find . \( -iname '*.jpg' -o -iname '*.jpeg' \) -print0 | xargs -0 -n 1 -P 4 jpegoptim --max=70 -s
```

But it fails on some images (jpegoptim receive SEGFAULT) and crash xargs, and all process fail.

How to skip fails, and continue task?

Thank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could wrap it up in a scriptlet, like:

```
find . \( -iname '*.jpg' -o -iname '*.jpeg' \) -print0 | \
  xargs -I@ -0 -n 1 -P 4 sh -c 'jpegoptim --max=70 -s "@" || exit 0'
```

, note that above won't handle some funnily named files (like e.g. with `"` in it).

[update: fixed for `sh -c '...'` as per comments]

Comment: correct: find . \( -iname '*.jpg' -o -iname '*.jpeg' \) -print0 | xargs -I@ -0 -n 1 -P 4 sh -c 'jpegoptim --max=70 -s "@" || exit 0'